# Write a function in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am new to React and js.

I am trying to write two text boxes such that the user will insert two numbers and when clicking Add button, he will get the result.

My suggestion was:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Home extends Component {
displayName = Home.name

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>Hello world! This is a new Web App</h1>

            <input type="text" name="" id="txt1" />
            +
            <input type="text" name="" id="txt1" />
            = <br/>
            <button onClick="add()">Add</button>

        </div>
      );
     }
    }
```

And I thought and a function add() that will do the following:

```
function add()
{
 var a = getElementById("txt1").value;
 var b = getElementById("txt2").value;
 alert(pardeInt(a)+parseInt(b));
}
```

If someone could edit my suggested code so it will work, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like you haven't read the first thing about how to use event handlers and form controls in react. Try https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: You are just using react to render HTML and use javascript. This has nothing to do with actual react. Start by reading more about react components please. Maybe follow some tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to `bind` the function to your context. This could be achieved by

```js
this.myFunction.bind()
```

or through arrow function (that bind function for you)

then you have to update the state (the render will be executed again when state change):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Home extends Component {
  state = { 
    result: 0,
    val1: 0,
    val2: 0,
  }

  handleChangeOne = (event) => {
    this.setState({val1: event.target.value});
  }
  
  handleChangeTwo = (event) => {
    this.setState({val2: event.target.value});
  }

  add = () =>
  {
   this.setState({
      result: parseInt(this.state.val1)+parseInt(this.state.val2)
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>Hello world! This is the result: {this.state.result}</h1>

            <input onChange={this.handleChangeOne} type="text" />
            +
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeTwo} />
            = <br/>
            <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>

        </div>
      );
     }
    }
```

Avoid to access directly to the DOM and rely to local state, instead.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you can assist me also here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984757/testing-a-react-component-with-jest

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just telling that you don't have React.js and React Native proper knowledge.

Definitely you should first take a look into React.js basis and THEN if you want to build mobile apps, the React-Native documentation:

- React.js documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html
- React Native documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html